# Publishing latest Build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have been playing with Jenkins and got it all working.  Version 1.447

However I would like to "publish" the latest stable build to an area outside the Jenkins workspace/job area.  This would be where users could pick up the latest stable build for testing and would save me having to point them to the .

Can someone recommend how I should go about approaching this?  Jenkins seems to have the ability to publish artefacts but only within the Jenkins workspace/area.  Is there a good plugin that can do what I want.  I'll also want to completely delete the existing build first.

Comment: I'd say you don't want to delete the existing build: in case QA finds a regression in the last stable build, having the previous ones around can come handy. Not to mention the demo effect.

Answer (score 9):

There are a bunch of plugins available for this, depending on how you want to transfer your artifact...

- [Publish over SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)
- [FTP-Publisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FTP-Publisher+Plugin)
- [Publish over CIFS](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin) (Windows Share)

If you go [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins), look for a section called `Artifact uploaders`, and it lists a bunch of others that you can use depending on your needs...

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this I add a post-build action to trigger a second job (build other projects -> projects to build, tick 'trigger only if build succeeds'). All this second job does is run a command (using the 'execute shell' field) which deploys the stable build for testing.

If you don't want to keep the existing build from the first job around, you can choose not to keep the builds after they have been run via the project config.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building maven project you could use maven 'deploy' to push build artifacts to your build repository (could be just a file structure anywhere or could be a true binary artifacts repository)